# How to place <Grid element> above other components in React's material-ui in a <Grid>

Tags: javascript, reactjs, layout, material-ui

How can we place  component above other components without braking responsive layout?

I have such layout:

```
  <Grid container justify='center'>
    <Grid item style={{ height: '100vh', width: '100%' }}>
        ... some background elements ...
    </Grid>
    <Grid item xs={12} sm={8} md={6} lg={4}>
        ... some input element on paper ...
    </Grid>
  </Grid>
```

I've tried to set `position: absolute`:

```
<Grid item xs={12} sm={8} md={6} lg={4} style={{position: 'absolute'}}>
```

It works but breaks the `xs={12} sm={8} md={6} lg={4}` breakpoint changes
How can I place one Grid item above other Grid item in a Grid? ([material-ui.com](http://material-ui.com))

Comment: Try splitting them into two separate Grid containers and applying the style to the container rather than the item.

Comment: Can you make a demo showing your problem? You can start from here if it helps: https://codesandbox.io/s/pp2p35q30q